# C# mvc get active menu item with menu items from partial controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I'm building a new website in mvc4 and I'm retrieving the menu dynamic from the database. To prevent doing the same actions over and over again in every controller and view to create the menu i'm using an partialcontroller with partial view to build the menu. I've done this thanks to [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1851625.aspx/1) article.

The next thing I want to achieve is to determine the current active menu item based on the current controller and action, so i've created an html helper to do this. The code is based on [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734579/adding-a-class-to-html-menuitems).

My code looks like this;

**Partialcontroller.cs**

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult MainMenu()
        {
            var viewModel = new MenuModel();

            try
            {
                IList<MenuItem> menuItems = MenuService.First(x => x.Name == "MainMenu").MenuItems;

                //Get the menuItems collection from somewhere
                if (menuItems != null && menuItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    viewModel.MenuItems = menuItems;
                    return View(viewModel);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //TODO: Exception handling and logging
            }

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

**MainMenu.cshtml**

This is the partial view which is included in the layout, and it among others contains this piece of code;

```
<nav class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="row-fluid nav">
        @foreach (var item in Model.MenuItems)
        {
            <li class="span2">
                @Html.MenuItem(item.Name, item.ActionName, item.ControllerName)
            </li>
        }

    </ul>
</nav>
```

**HtmlHelper.cs**

The htmlhelper method i'm using in the partial view to build the menu items. This one is where the problem is.

```
public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
        {
            string currentAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
            string currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
            if (actionName == currentAction && controllerName == currentController)
            {
                return htmlHelper.ActionLink(
                    linkText,
                    actionName,
                    controllerName,
                    null,
                    new
                    {
                        @class = "active"
                    });
            }

            //var link = htmlHelper.ActionLink("<span>{LinkText}<span>", actionName, controllerName).ToHtmlString();
            //return new MvcHtmlString(link.Replace("{LinkText}", linkText));

            return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName);
        }
```

When debugging I see that the variable 'currentController' contains the value 'Partial' and the variable 'currentAction' contains 'MainMenu'. All seems quite logic to me since this is the controller action used to build the menu. 
However, this is also the issue. The two variables will always contain the values 'Partial' and 'MainMenu' because the MenuItem helper is always called in an view instantiated by the PartialController. This way i'm never able to match the actual controller making the request.

All I want to do is, for example click the contact-button in the menu and see it as the active menu item. The action for this menu-item could be the Index action of the ContactController, so if the controller and the action match with the controller and the action mapped with the menu-item, an additional css-class should be added.

What can I do to solve this? I prefer to do it in code instead of dirty javascript functions, but I don't know if it's possible or how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think you can access the parent controller using the ParentActionViewContext property on htmlHelper.ViewContext

```
string currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that.. Wish everything was so simple! This worked like a charm:)